# Convert unique DataFrame rows to tree structure in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, tree

I have a pandas DataFrame of unique rows which looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'O': ['O-1','O-1'],
                       'B': ['B-1','B-2'],
                       'C': ['C-1','C-2'],
                       'R': ['R-1','R-1']}, 
                       columns = ['O', 'B', 'C', 'R'])
```

Columns of `df` are ordered in parent-child linear relation, wherein column `O` is level 1, column `B` is level 2 and so on. The intention is to convert this `df` into a tree like structure for navigation purposes, which would look something like this:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'PARENT': ['O-1','O-1','O-1','O-1','O-1','B-1','B-1','B-2','B-2','C-1','C-2'],
                       'CHILD_TYPE': ['B','B','C','C','R','C','R','C','R','R','R'],
                       'CHILD': ['B-1','B-2','C-1','C-2','R-1','C-1','R-1','C-2','R-1','R-1','R-1']},
                        columns = ['PARENT', 'CHILD_TYPE', 'CHILD'])
```

Filtering on each column's each value in `df` (as parent) then copying all unique values of remaining columns on the right as child seems like a bad way to achieve this.

Is there an efficient way?

Comment: `O-2` is not in your output, why is that

Comment: my bad, it should be `O-1` in that array. I'll just correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, we have this way to achieve this:

> Filtering on each column's each value in df (as parent) then copying all unique values of remaining columns on the right as child seems like a bad way to achieve this.

And the solution with same logic is here:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'O': ['O-1','O-1'],
                   'B': ['B-1','B-2'],
                   'C': ['C-1','C-2'],
                   'R': ['R-1','R-1']}, columns = ['O', 'B', 'C', 'R'])

ls = []
for col in sample:
    for val in sample[col]:
        fs = sample[sample[col] == val]
        fvl = fs.iloc[:,fs.columns.get_loc(col)+1:].T.values.tolist()
        fcl = fs.iloc[:,fs.columns.get_loc(col)+1:].columns.tolist()
        for fc, fvs in zip(fcl, fvl):
            for fv in fvs:
                ls.append([val,fc,fv])

output = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns = ['PARENT', 'CHILD_TYPE', 'CHILD']).drop_duplicates()
```